# Haskell Network.HTTP.Conduit Exception: InvalidProxyEnvironmentVariable "http_proxy"

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I'm using the simple example from HTTP.Conduit's documentation found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html).

```
   import Network.HTTP.Conduit
   import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
   main = simpleHttp "http://www.haskell.org/" >>= L.putStr
```

My system requires a proxy which is set with the environmental variable `http_proxy` and has the form `http://user:pass@proxy:port/`.

Http.Conduit results in an exception with the error:

```
  *** Exception: InvalidProxyEnvironmentVariable "http_proxy" "http://user:pass@proxy:port/"
```

(I've changed the details for the proxy..)

What is the issue? Does Http.Conduit not support authentication?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you have the same issue and need some way to get data via HTTP, you can consider using `Network.Curl` which given a test I just did seems to work even with proxy settings for the obvious reasons.

Comment: `http-client` doesn't support proxies with auth (at the moment), see https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/issues/129.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of http-client, which has now [been reported](https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/issues/129) and [resolved](https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/commit/f6397dcc2a7472b34c986ab54ac854cb3fb08fa5). This change will get released to Hackage in the next few days, testing and success reports welcome!